# Incorrect results when using group by date_part

Tags: greenplum

We have a table with a date field and ids. A simple query like this returns the correct result:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT id_field) AS distinct_count FROM schema1.table1 WHERE date_part('month', date_field ) = 11 ;

distinct_count
----------------------
            5645202
```

However, when trying to count distinct ids grouped by month we get incorrect results:

```
SELECT date_part('month',date_field ), count(DISTINCT id_field) AS distinct_count
FROM schema1.table1 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1 desc;

date_part | distinct_count
-----------+----------------------
        12 |              5637167
        11 |              5645426
        10 |              5705702
         9 |              5633101
         8 |              5619553
         7 |              5636407
         6 |              5598244
         5 |              5658568
         4 |              5591066
         3 |              5595882
         2 |              5646399
         1 |              5584825
(12 rows)
```

Month 11 has 5,645,426 IDs counted (incorrect) vs 5,645,202 (correct). Could this be an issue with the DB engine itself?

Comment: Could be an issue with anything really, but with the level of detail provided it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Not sure what other details I can provide. Looking for any suggestions on what could cause this.

Comment: Well, you could start by explaining how you know which value is correct and which is not. You could post the actual table definition and the explain plans for both queries. You could try `COUNT()` without `DISTINCT` and check if it also arrives at different values.